# Mongoose / Express Middleware update reference documents at insert time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Given the below code, and the fact that I'm using mongoose `populate()` in my API, how can I update the `user` reference document with the checkin `_id`, at the same time?

I feel it's like the chicken/problem. Thanks!

```
router.post('/', (req, res, err) => {
  var checkin = new Checkin(req.body);
  var user    = new User(checkin.user);

  checkin.save({
    'user':             checkin.user,
    'checkin_comment':  checkin.checkin_comment,
    'rating_score':     checkin.rating_score
  });
});
```

The `Checkin` model has the following:

```
user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
```

.. and the `User` one has this:

```
checkins: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Checkin'
  }],
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your model definition, it seems that attribute `checkins` on the User model is optional. The user can exists without checkin reference.

If that's the case then create the user first, then the checkin and update the user with its id.

**Edit**: Given your comments, we assume that the user already exists in DB and its id available in `userId`.

So something like:

```
checkin.save()
    .then((checkinDoc) => {
      return User.findOneAndUpdate(
            {_id: userId},
            {$push:{checkins: checkinDoc._id}},
            {new: true}
      );
    });
```

Comment: Yes indeed. The user can already exist in the DB without any checkins. The scenario is that the user would action the checkin, enter a comment and a rating. The trigger is the checkin service that would be called to add a new checkin to the DB.

Comment: Re-reading your comment, you assume that the user isn't in the DB yet, correct? In my case, the user would always be in the DB, prior to their first check-in.

Comment: Then I don't understand your problem. If one of the model creation fail, the other will reference a non existing model. It should be done sequentially to ensure data integrity.

Comment: Yes I assumed that your user wasn't in the DB yet.

Comment: _Then I don't understand your problem. If one of the model creation fail, the other will reference a non existing model. It should be done sequentially to ensure data integrity_ <-- Agreed. What if, in my case, the user already exists. What would be the approach, what that user checks-in, and we want to reference that checkin into his doc?

Comment: I'll assume that you have the userId when creating the checkin document. So create the checkin document, and update the user document with checkin ref. Same than in my original answer but without the `user.save`. IMHO this is typically why I switched to PostgreSQL ;) These types of relationships updates are already managed out of the box.

Comment: When trying your last EDIT, `checkinDoc._id` is `null` even though it gets correctly inserted into the DB. The `user. findOneAndUpdate ` does not work then.

Comment: Sorry, following the doc, it should be the second parameter, first one is the error. I haven't used mongoose in some time! http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save

Comment: Actually in this doc, they show it as the first result so I don't know, I guess you have to try : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: I think the code is correct... Just that it does not seem to return the `_id`, 
`{
 checkin_date: 2018-01-22T18:35:08.101Z,
  _id: null,
  checkin_comment: 'grrr..',
  rating_score: 2.5,
  user: 5a5dc5859e082a15e3d9adcd,
  created_at: 2018-01-22T18:35:08.108Z,
  updated_at: 2018-01-22T18:35:08.108Z,
  __v: 0
}`